# Salesforce staged to closed/won after completed signature

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to do this in docusign connect but with no luck.  the documentation for Docsugin for Sales force isn't helping since i'm a noob.

Are there an tutorials on how to set this up?

Example.
I send the docusign via sales force from an opportunity.  the reciever signs the document.  I can see the docusing status at bottom of opp. update to complete.  now i how do i get the opp. to update the stage to complete/won?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [DocuSign for Salesforce: Adding Completed Documents to the Notes and Attachments](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Adding-Completed-Documents-to-the-Notes-and-Attachments1)

You'll want to create a custom object in the DocuSign Connect > Salesforce config as per the instructions above. Stop at step 8 above, and instead add an Update Fields line that maps the Salesforce field: Stage to the custom text value you want to set. Example:
[image: Connect config]

Comment: This helped.  I knew it was something easy, I just couldnt find the documentation on docusign anywhere.  thanks for your help!  it worked.